# "DisableCreatedUser" is not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, login-control, createuserwizard

I am using a `ASP.NET` `CreateUserWizard` to registering users. 
I wanted user to not automatically log after registration until they login manually.

```
    <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="RegisterUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" RequireEmail="false"
DisableCreatedUser="true" LoginCreatedUser="false" OnCreatedUser="RegisterUser_CreatedUser">
```

In here I have set the `DisableCreatedUser="true"` and `LoginCreatedUser="false"` in order to not logged the user after registration until they logged in as [CreateUserWizard.DisableCreatedUser Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard.disablecreateduser.aspx) describes.

Any ideas about the reason this settings not working will be appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: What is "not working" about it? Are you editing the correct web.config?

Comment: currently user login automatically after registration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did that by adding `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()` in the `OnCreatedUser`. that works !!!